# Sailsjs - Cloud SDK - Blueprint API auto generated routes?

Tags: sails.js

I wonder if it is possible to have the Blueprint API support in Cloud SDK.
But apparently, the generated `cloud.setup.js` file does not contain blueprint APIs. Just normal routes beginning with `/api`

It is written in the `Cloud.js` file :

   `* ### Basic Usage
   *
   * var user = await Cloud.findOneUser(3);
   *
   * var user = await Cloud.findOneUser.with({ id: 3 });`

It lets think that it's possible to have auto generated routes to the blueprint APIs like `actionModel` -> `findOneUser`, `createServer`, `addToGame`, and so on...

Do you know if that is possible ? I don't find a documentation about this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also asked this question the other day. It is not possible. We need to be explicit here. Blueprint routes is only for quick integration testing with postman. I don't recommend this though. You should not be using postman or auto routes. You should write tests in files so they are permanent.

Comment: It seemed logic. Thanks

Comment: Thank you @Sw0ut!

Comment: you should not ask that, and if I asked a good question you should upvote it also.

Answer (score 1):

I took original code in rebuild-cloud-sdk.js and created a rcsdk.js with the code below before the actual `for (let address in sails.config.routes)`:

```
_.each(_.keys(sails.models), model => {
    let action = sails.config.blueprints.prefix + sails.config.blueprints.restPrefix + '/' + model;
    _.each([['GET', 'find'], ['POST', 'create']], pair => {
        endpointsByMethodName[`${pair[1]}${model}`] = {
          verb: pair[0],
          url: action,
        }
    });
    _.each([['GET', 'findOne'], ['PUT', 'update'], ['DELETE', 'delete']], pair => {
        endpointsByMethodName[`${pair[1]}${model}`] = {
          verb: pair[0],
          url: action,
          args: ['id'],
        }
    });
});
```